# Is there any javascript api through which I can get call duration and cost?

Tags: twilio

I'm trying to establish a call with javascript client:

```
function call() { 
// get the phone number or client to connect the call to 
params = {"PhoneNumber": $("#number").val()}; 
Twilio.Device.connect(params); 
}
```

Is there any javascript api through which I can get call duration and cost?

Maybe in this call back api:

```
Twilio.Device.connect(function (conn) { 
$("#log").text("Successfully established call"); 
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Twilio employee here.

With our REST API you can query information on calls that are in progress or that have happened and they include details on the cost and duration of the call.

Have a look here for information: https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/call#instance-properties.

Please be aware however that you shold **not** make API requests from JavaScript as you would have to expose your Twilio credentials in clear text within script, which is obviously not something you want to do.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried to get call duration of forwarded call. So i used the following api:         `code` $client = new Services_Twilio($twilio_account_sid, $twilio_auth_token);
        $call_fwds = $client->account->calls->getIterator(0, 1, array("Status" => "completed", "ParentCallSid" => $CallSid));
        foreach ($call_fwds as $callfwd){
            $duration = $callfwd->duration;
        } `code`
but problem is it works fine in local(wamp) host and it goes infinite in server. Can you give me some idea of why it does not work in server(lamp)?